# GDI & Hardware Cursor

Tags: embedded, windows-ce, hardware-interface

I am working on iMX51 project.
    The RTOS is WINCE 6.0 r3. 
    And I am using iMX51 freescale evaluation kit.

**We are actually looking to speed up the GDI and to implement the hardware cursor.**

*I am unclear abt the following*:-

1. What exactly does speed up of ***GDI & Hardware cursor*** means?
2. Also What is the difference b/w ***software & hardware cursors***?

***Note***: `When I reboot the hardware after building my workspace, I see the mouse cursor located at the centre of the window. Can anyone guide me what type of cursor is this? Is this a hardware cursor or software cursor...? And if this is a hardware cursor then:----`

1. How should I eliminate the software cursor ?
2. What should I do to implement the hardware cursor?
3. And why should I do this?
4. And on which module I should look to achieve the target?

**Referring:**

- WC600_MX51_SDK_0912_ReferenceManual.pdf
- MCIMX51RM.pdf

> Please guide me the correct step to
>   how to achieve my target.

Comment: Please note, this question has nothing to do with C and C++, which is why I removed the tags. Why did you reinstate them?

Comment: Why not include Delphi, assembler, FORTH and any other language that "might" be used? I don't want to get into an edit war on this but please remove those tags.

Comment: @anon Because sometimes people get pissy if you don't include the language you're working the question in. And some people get pissy when you do...

Answer (score 4):

The cursor is simply the mouse pointer. Having a hardware cursor means that the graphics hardware can "overlay" a small moving image (often called a "[sprite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprite_%28computer_graphics%29)") on top of the regular graphics, by itself.

Implementing a software cursor means storing the background "below" the pointer, and re-writing that when the pointer moves. It can be tricky, especially when the underlying graphics is changing.

UPDATE: From a quick glance at the [reference manual](http://cache.freescale.com/files/dsp/doc/ref_manual/MCIMX51RM.pdf?fpsp=1), you need to read up on the display processor (DP) module. The register `DP_COC_SYNC` seems to be concerned with setting up the cursor mode, while `DP_CUR_POS_SYNC` sets its position on-screen.

Comment: @abhi - we have no way to know.  You have to look at your display driver source code and see which it's using.